# Bash while loop with read and IFS

Tags: bash, while-loop, ifs

I have to parse a file in the following format:

```
line1_param1:line1_param2:line1_param3:
line1_param2:line2_param2:line2_param3:
line1_param3:line3_param2:line3_param3:
```

And process it line by line, extracting all parameters from current line. Currently I've managed it in such a way:

```
IFS=":"
grep "nice" some_file | sort > tmp_file
while read param1 param2 param3
do
  ..code here..
done < tmp_file
unset IFS
```

How can I avoid a creation of a temporary file?

Unfortunately this doesn't work correctly:

```
IFS=":"
while read param1 param2 param3
do
  ..code here..
done <<< $(grep "nice" some_file | sort)
unset IFS
```

As the whole line is assigned to the param1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**process substitution**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) for this:

```
while IFS=: read -r param1 param2 param3
do
   echo "Any code here to process: $param1 $param2 $param3"
done < <(grep "nice" some_file | sort)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, you can enable the `lastpipe` option to use the "natural" pipeline. The `while` loop will execute in the current shell, not a subshell, so and variables you set or change will still be visible following the pipeline. (Stealing code from anubhava's fine answer to demonstrate.)

```
shopt -s lastpipe
grep "nice" some_file | sort | while IFS=: read -r param1 param2 param3
do
   echo "Any code here to process: $param1 $param2 $param3"
done
```