# BASH problem with IFS within nested while loops reading from MySQL

Tags: bash, nested-loops, delimiter, do-while, ifs

I am having a problem with my `bash` script -- And I think honestly it's a matter of understanding IFS completely.

I have read multiple questions on SO but seem to be going in circles I think because none address the issue specifically having to do with MySQL ...  But I'll defer to your expertise on that.
First here is the script I am having trouble with:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --login-path=main-data -Nse "SELECT b.name, a.section_id
FROM some_table" | while read section_name section_id; do

echo "$section_name - $section_id"

    mysql --login-path=main-data -Nse "SELECT a.page_id, b.page_url
                FROM some_table" | while read page_id page_url; do
                echo "    - $page_url";
    done

 get_children() {
        mysql --login-path=main-data -Nse " SELECT b.sections_id, b.name
        FROM some_table" | while read child_id section_name; do
            echo "  -- $section_name";
            # If statement goes here -- Then recursive
            if [[ $child_id = *[!\ ]* ]]; then
            section_id=$child_id

            # Now get pages for child sections
            mysql --login-path=main-data -Nse "SELECT page_id, page_url
            FROM some_table" | while read page_id page_url; do
                echo "        - $page_url";
            done

            get_children $section_id
            fi

        done
    }

    get_children $section_id

done
```

If I run my script without `IFS` as-is the output looks like:

```
HOME - 732
    - Home.htm
    - Home2.htm
    - Nome3.htm
WHY - US        742
ROOFING - 743
    - Residential-Roofing.htm
  -- Certainteed
        - CertOverview.htm
```

The issue comes with "WHY US"  --  If you notice the dash ended up in the wrong spot --  Obviously a delimiter issue because there is a space there ..  Now if I change the first loop to :

```
mysql --login-path=main-data -Nse "SELECT a.page_id, b.page_url
FROM some_table" | while IFS='\n' read page_id page_url; do
```

My output becomes :

```
HOME    732 - 
WHY US  742 - 
ROOFING 743 -
```

Which you'll notice the dashes are ALL in the wrong spot but "WHY US" has the correct space in it.  **In addition to that** my nested loops did not run.  I am thoroughly confused about the "correct" way to deal with spaces in these names, and still get the desired nested output!  Where am I going wrong?

> > **RESOURCES**
> >
> > [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034012/bash-shell-script-nested-while-loop-with-ifs)
> >     This one addresses IFS while nested, but in the wrong context, unusable
> >
> > [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638795/bash-while-loop-with-read-and-ifs)
> >     Again same issue ... Obviously I tried what they have in the answer section to no avail.

Comment: How should you tell the boundary between "section_name" and "section_id"?

Comment: you should IFS=$'\t' mysql outputs tab separated output by default, as i recol. But if you have tabs in strings, you are left with parsing html output

Comment: General note: when changing `IFS`, you should change it for as small a section of the script as possible to minimize unexpected side effects. In this case, if @KamilCuk's suggestion does solve it, you probably want to change `IFS` *only* for the `read` commands. You can do this by making the assignment a prefix to the `read` command, like this:  `... | while IFS=$'\t' read ...`

Comment: I have tried `while IFS=$'\t' read` and the output looks still like the second "un-nested" result